# Styling option tags

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down that contains options.  I would like to partially break & bold some text as well as insert context breaks. I tried using CSS as well as HTML tags but I'm unable to get it. Can someone please suggest a solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13):

I know this question is a bit old (or not new at least), but I'd like to show a very simple way to emulate a select element rather than using a "replacement plugin" as suggested in [How to style the option of a html “select”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select).

There are probably many, MANY ways to do this, but I try to keep things extremely simple, so my method of emulation only uses CSS.  It is rather bare bones, but I'd like to point out that it is not a complicated thing to do so you might not need a plug in to do it.

**Note1:** Instead of using `<option>`, I used `<label>`.  Since `<label>` is an interactive element, putting something interactive inside (like a `<button>`) would probably mess it up.  Options are normally non-interactive anyway, but just be aware that this simple emulation can't do everything.

**Note2:** If you want to be able to select multiple options, just do a search for "radio" and replace with "checkbox".

---

### [Emulating Select Using Radio - No Collapse](https://jsfiddle.net/undoingtech/mhvhvgo9/)

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: black;
  color: #28AADC;
}

/* none functional styles.  just regular styling */
.radio_select {
  background-color: #28AADC;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio_select">
  <div>
    <input id="rad1" type="radio" name="radio_select" />
    <label for="rad1">Option 1</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input id="rad2" type="radio" name="radio_select" checked="checked" />
    <label for="rad2">Option 2</label>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <input id="rad3" type="radio" name="radio_select" />
    <label for="rad3">Option 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### [Radio select emulation - with collapse](https://jsfiddle.net/undoingtech/L45rq1L8/)

Note: this won't work for mobile devices since it uses `:hover`.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

/* style this to your heart's content */

input[type="radio"] + label {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: black;
  color: #28AADC;
  display: inline-block;
}

.radio_select:hover label {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* none functional styles.  just regular styling */

.radio_select {
  background-color: #28AADC;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- NOTE:  This technique uses hover, so it won't work for mobile devices.
  I couldn't think of a pure CSS way to solve that.  Sorry. -->

<div class="radio_select">
  <div>
    <input id="rad1" type="radio" name="radio_select" />
    <label for="rad1">Option 1</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input id="rad2" type="radio" name="radio_select" />
    <label for="rad2">Option 2</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input id="rad3" type="radio" name="radio_select" checked="checked" />
    <label for="rad3">Option 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to make these options flow on top of elements below them. Currently if you add something under this div, then the div move up and down depending on whether the dropdown is open or closed

Comment: @Frank here's a JSFiddle to ignore the "options" size. https://jsfiddle.net/5xmb34Lj/
I just added a container with a `position: relative;` and set the radio_select with a `position: absolute;`.